# Loop through error messages without withErrors($validator) in Laravel - foreach

Tags: php, laravel

How can I look through errors in a Controller in Laravel from a failed validator?

I know I can use this:

```
return Redirect::route('account-create')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
```

But I need a string to manipulate with it in the same method, so how can I use a foreach to iterate over the errors and append it to a single string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can grab the error messages by using `$validator->errors();` which would return an instance of `MessageBag`.  You could then call `getMessages()` on that to get an array of the messages returned.

Example...

```
$messages = $validator->errors()->getMessages();
var_dump($messages);
```